# Define xml element as unique using xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, unique

I have an xml file with the associated xsd below:

The element "name" of complexType "UpgraderConfig" needs to be unique.
I have added "unique" tag to "UpgraderConfigContainer" definition, yet cannot seem to get the desired behaviour.

Can anyone please advise as to what I am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.hp.com/maas/1.0.0/UpgraderConfig"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:config="http://www.hp.com/maas/1.0.0/UpgraderConfig"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           version="1.0.0">

    <xs:simpleType name="stringWithoutWhiteSpace">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>One or more occurrences of any character which is not whitespace (i.e. not space, tab, newline, return)</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1" />
            <xs:pattern value="\S+" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>


    <xs:complexType name="UpgraderConfigContainer">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Upgrader" type="config:UpgraderConfig" >
                <xs:unique name="uniqueUgraderName">
                    <xs:selector xpath="Upgrader"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="name"/>
                </xs:unique>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="UpgraderConfig">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="className" type="config:stringWithoutWhiteSpace"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="UpgraderConfigs" type="config:UpgraderConfigContainer" />

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the unique constrain too low. An element of itself can not be unique. Only the container containing it can have the unique constrain. You have labelled `UpgraderConfigContainer` a bit miss-leading, because it is not the container. Instead it is the element, which is unbound, which means that you have zero or more `UpgraderConfigContainer`s. The element containing `UpgraderConfigContainer` must have the unique constrain. You have to add it to `UpgraderConfigs`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:config="http://www.hp.com/maas/1.0.0/UpgraderConfig" targetNamespace="http://www.hp.com/maas/1.0.0/UpgraderConfig" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0.0">
    <xs:simpleType name="stringWithoutWhiteSpace">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>One or more occurrences of any character which is not whitespace (i.e. not space, tab, newline, return)</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:pattern value="\S+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="UpgraderConfigContainer">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="Upgrader" type="config:UpgraderConfig"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="UpgraderConfig">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="className" type="config:stringWithoutWhiteSpace"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="UpgraderConfigs" type="config:UpgraderConfigContainer">
        <xs:unique name="uniqueUpgraderName">
            <xs:selector xpath="config:Upgrader"/>
            <xs:field xpath="config:name"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I did not know the containing element only can have the unique constraint on it. Thank you, it indeed works.